# How to convert TreeGrid to Json

Tags: extjs, ext4

I have one question about Tree and Json. In most cases you just get Json and with its help you can build your Tree (TreeGrid). Is there any possible just to convert your Tree to Json?

For example: You click on the button and than your tree will be converted to Json and send to a webservice.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the root node from the store and then convert it to whatever format you like.

```
 root = myTreeGrid.getStore().getRootNode()
 rootNodeData = root.data
 children = root.childNodes
```